# Gerrit LDAP mandatoryGroup

Tags: ldap, gerrit

How do config mandatoryGroup in Gerrit's LDAP? My gerrit.conf is currently like this... I'm not sure if the mandatoryGroup value should be LDAP syntax or plan text. I can not figure this out based on documentation.

https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-gerrit.html#ldap

```
ldap.mandatoryGroup

All users must be a member of this group to allow account creation or authentication.

Setting mandatoryGroup implies enabling of ldap.fetchMemberOfEagerly

By default, unset.
```

gerrit.config

```
[ldap]
    server = ldaps://company.com
    sslVerify = false
    username = ldapUsername
    password = ldapPassword
    accountBase = DC=COMPANY_DOMAIN,DC=LOCAL
    groupBase = DC=COMPANY_DOMAIN,DC=LOCAL
    referral = follow
    accountPattern = (sAMAccountName=${username})
    groupPattern = (cn=${groupname})
    accountFullName = displayName
    accountMemberField = memberOf
    accountEmailAddress = mail
    mandatoryGroup = grp_IT_SourceCode
```

Answer (score 0):

mandatoryGroup = ldap/"AD_Group_Name" worked for me... I'm not sure why but the "ldap/" was required before the AD group and all is good now.